# How to capture video from an external camera using opencv on ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, camera

I am a beginner to ubuntu. I am trying to drive a external camera on ubuntu 15.04. I want to know how to combine opencv library with camera driver. So I can capture video use sentences like 
`VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);//0,1,2...`

Does anyone have some idea? Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: not 100% sure but afaik it has to with linux device nodes, so video0 will be used by .open(0) and so on. But I don't know whether that's all which is needed or whether there are additional requirement. Maybe look at: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Webcam-HOWTO/#DEV-MANUAL

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea about linux device nodes. I will learn more about it to find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the camera you use, some cameras you need do nothing, and some cameras give API,you can use the API to get the video then use opencv to do something.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am using Logitech Webcam C930e. As you said, I need do nothing. Maybe I can use luvcview for other cameras.